# Error in Scala compiler: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to integrate Scala-2.10.4 along with Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 and getting into the following error.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Error in Scala compiler: GC overhead limit exceeded spark-core      Unknown Scala Problem
```

I tried modifying memory limit on eclipse.ini.

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
```

This still does not help. I have tried restarting eclipse and refreshing the project. 
System details : MAC 10.8.5
EDIT :

I am trying to setup Spark codebase to work with Eclipse editor and following instructions from here : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Useful+Developer+Tools#UsefulDeveloperTools-IDESetup

I tried setting the compiler option on scala to -Xmx2048m and that does not work either. I am getting the following error[image]

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. You're setting MaxPermSize, when you probably need to set the max heap size.  Use the "-Xmx2048m" command line switch to set the heap size to 2gb.
2. You're setting values into the eclipse executable, not the scala compiler executable.

Assuming you're using ScalaIDE, it seems you can add compiler parameters as follows.  Under eclipse menu "Preferences", open "Scala" then "Compiler", then see the field labeled "Additional command line parameters".

I tried adding "-Xmx2048m" here, but the field indicates an error; I tried adding "-J-Xmx2048m" and no error is indicated, so perhaps that will work for you.

Comment: I tried this and I still get the same error. I have made edits to my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the maven dependencies, In my case the missing jars was causing the compiler to through this error. I had to fix delete the missing links from the .m2 repository and and then update the project to re-download the dependencies. This resolved the issue and the error stopped appearing. Learning from JimN's explanation, switching on the verbose would give us better clue of what is causing the fault. Though this is not a straight fix to the issue mentioned. I believe the actual error is masked and over-consuming the heap causing eclipse to throw the GC overhead limit exceed error. Post back your observations so that it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Under eclipse menu "Preferences" > "Scala" > "Compiler", then in "Additional command line parameters" add "`-J-Xmx2048m`" or "`-J-Xmx1024m`"

Restart eclipse or refresh the project it should be fixed.